# Processing of contacts in a Journey

Tags: marketing-cloud

Scenario::
We have put a Data Extension as the source of a Journey,The Data Extension can have upto 500K records.This journey will be running on a continuous basis and will allow reentry.
Question ::
Does Marketing cloud process the DE sequentially record by record and once it has gone through all the records then start reentering the contacts from the first record?

Comment: Just to further elaborate :The question is NOT about journey schedule/How to select a DE/reentry modes, If there is a large data set to process for valid Journey entrants then does MC goes in a sequential pattern through a datestamp or how does it prioritize one record over another ?

Answer (score 0):

I was close to downvoting your question because it can be solved by taking a look at the documentation. Please take a look at [this page](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_data_extension.htm&type=5) and you will find your answer along with a best practice recommendation.

Comment: Thanks,I could see frequency of entry, any filter we want to put through or the specific source selection and we are aware of these parameters,I am asking for a large data set does Marketing Cloud go sequentially through the DE  for sending emails or SMS,I couldn't find any specific  literature on that,Could you please let me know if you are seeing something specific in those lines .

Comment: The lines say that you can choose to reevaluate all records but shouldn't. Standard behaviour: it goes sequentially through all records at first and then evaluates new ones. The concept behind this is the so called "high watermark" from where it starts evaluating records in every new run